# Angular get dynamic variable from $scope inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm unable to output a variable within my $scope inside an ng-repeat

The following variables are defined inside my $scope: **error_question1** , **error_question2** , **error_question3**

I have the below  inside an ng-repeat and I'm trying to assign the span's value to the corresponding variable within my $scope using the ng-repeat's $index.

I can get this working by directly targeting the variable but obviously it duplicates for every item in my ng-repeat like so:

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="error_question{{$index + 1}}">{{error_question2}}</span>
```

However, the way I imagine it working does not work:

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="error_question{{$index + 1}}">{{error_question[$index + 1]}}</span>
```

The [$index+1] appears to be breaking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by doing `{{error_question[$index + 1]}}` you are basically saying "get me the item at the position `$index + 1` of the `error_question` array". That's not what you want.

Try using a different approach. Instead of having all the **error_question1, error_question2, ... error_questionX** floating around in the `$scope`, use an object to encapsulate the errors. Like this:

```
$scope.errors = {
  question1: ...,
  question2: ...,
  question3: ...,
  ...
};
```

This way you can use it in the HTML like this:

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="errors.question{{$index + 1}}">{{errors['question' + ($index + 1)]}}</span>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JoeNxpIfgOatFRw9kqIQ?p=preview)